# How to use edittext (number decimal) to integer

Tags: android

I am trying to make basic click counter app which will count the number of clicks, but along with that I want to have a **EditText** to put the desired number and on click, it will double that up and show in **TextView**.

I tried `accCount + tCount ++;`

But it did not work,

I tried one more solution provided by the user named moon, it was very helpful but it was adding its own value but itself.
what am I doing wrong?

code:

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.patta.drawerrrrr.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/touchCountText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="touchFunc"
    android:text="@string/_0"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="150sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#ff1e00"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="reset"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:text="RESET"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="400dp" />
```

JAVA:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    Vibrator vibrator;
    EditText editText;
    TextView touchCountText;
    int tCount = 0;
    int accCount = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        vibrator = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        touchCountText = findViewById(R.id.touchCountText);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);

        int accCount = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());


    }

    public void touchFunc (View v){
        tCount++;
        touchCountText.setText(""+tCount);
        vibrator.vibrate(40);
    }
    public void reset (View v){
        tCount = 0;
        touchCountText.setText(""+tCount);
        vibrator.vibrate(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: set a TextWatcher on EditText

Comment: on what click you are increasing your count there is no button or click listener mentioned

Comment: `editText(accCount);` --> what does it mean? and also in your `touchFunc (View v)`  you have used **""+tCount + ""+accCount** which will concatenate the values ,will not add it.

Comment: @vikaskumar: sorry, its on touch rather than click.   and joe: sorry  about tthat, but i tried to add the value of tCount and accCount(which is int) to touchCountText, and i am failing to do that.

Comment: even if its a touch then where is your onTouch listener you are missing some code here i guess.

Comment: @vikaskumar: please see it now ,,, its on touch rather than click.

Comment: is touchFunc onclick method of any button? where you are clicking?

Comment: @joe: i have attached xml, and yes touchFunc is clickable

Comment: @RaviKilnake Try my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code,

```
Vibrator vibrator;
EditText editText;
TextView touchCountText;
int tCount = 0;
static double accCount = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    vibrator = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    touchCountText =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.touchCountText);
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

    DrawerLayout drawer =(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle
            (this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


}

public void touchFunc (View v){
    if(!editText.getText().toString().isEmpty() && tCount==0)
        accCount = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
    else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"editText is empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    tCount++;
    Log.d("value",String.valueOf(accCount));
    touchCountText.setText(String.valueOf((double)tCount*accCount));
    vibrator.vibrate(40);
}
public void reset (View v){
    tCount = 0;
    accCount=0; 
    touchCountText.setText(String.valueOf(tCount));
    vibrator.vibrate(100);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)){
        tCount--;
        touchCountText.setText(String.valueOf((double)tCount*accCount));
        vibrator.vibrate(40);
    }
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)){
        tCount++;
        touchCountText.setText(String.valueOf((double)tCount*accCount));
        vibrator.vibrate(40);
    }
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
    return false;
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: sir, i tried it but it is not adding the value of editText, it is adding itself (tCount) i.e; 1-3-7-15... and so on.

Comment: do u want to increment the value from edittext? For ex, if it is 25 u need ans like 26,27,28 so on?

Comment: no, i am trying to get it like : if the number entered is 2.5 

then it should show 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10 and so on .

Comment: could you please explain accCount as double;?

Comment: if you need decimal values, you can use double. you told 2.5 for ex. that's why I suggested double

Comment: now on touch, it just changes the value from 0 to 0.0.. no matter how many times i touch, and still not taking value from editText.

Comment: try Log, and say what value you are getting from accCount.

Comment: Log.d("value",String.valueOf(accCount)); use this, see accCount value in your log cat

Comment: Just to track where the problem occured

Comment: D/value: 0.0
D/value: 0.0

Comment: @RaviKilnake this code will work fine. I think there is a problem with getting edittext string. Check whether you have given correct Id of edittext and check accCount value is assigned. I have editted my answer

Comment: joe i tried your method, and changes few things myself aswell . but it didnt work, have a look at my entire code
https://pastebin.com/sjUuf1mY

Comment: @RaviKilnake Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48637785/8867002) will help.

Comment: I tried, it is still just changing the value from 0 to 0.0, even after entering the value. :(

Comment: did u get the toast "edittext is empty" ? ,remove if else statement and simply use `accCount = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());` and uninstall app, try file -> invalidate caches & restart . Then run the app

Comment: @RaviKilnake I got that mistake. Get the value from edittext in onTouch function . See My edited answer

Answer (score 0):

If I did not misunderstand your question

```
int valueFromEditText=0;


editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        valueFromEditText=Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString().trim());
        yourTextViewToDisplayDoubleValue.setText(valueFromEditText*2+"");

        }
    });
```

Comment: i tried this, but i tha app is crashing,,, 

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" <-- this is from logcat

Comment: as i have touchFunc clickable .. i tried your code, but its giving me an error and app crashes on just the touchFunc, rest is working fine,      Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)<-- this is the new error

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it wrong way

```
editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
int accCount = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
```

**reason**:

you can't simply get the text from EditText and parse empty text into an Integer when EditText is just initialized it will probably throw an exception.

so you should first check or just initialize the EditText with default value of **Zero** or something for the first time and then on click of some button or something do something like this.

```
int count = 0;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //your other code ...............
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    //default value
    editText.setText(String.valueOf(count));   
 }

@Override
public void onClick(View view){
 //button click
 count++
 //double the value and show in editText
 editText.setText(String.valueOf(count*2))
}
```